# WPF DragDrop in DatagridTemplateColumn not working

Tags: wpf

WPF is driving me crazy again.

Could someone please tell me why dropping items works with a regular DatagridTextColumn like this:

```
    <DataGridTextColumn
                Width="0.2*"
                Binding="{Binding ActiveMacro.Displayname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                ElementStyle="{StaticResource cellLeftTextStyle}"
                Header="Test"
                IsReadOnly="True" />
```

but not with a DataGridTemplateColumn like that:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="0.2*" Header="Name">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBox
                        AllowDrop="True"
                        DragEnter="TextBox_DragEnter"
                        Drop="ActiveMacro_Drop"
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        Text="{Binding CombinedState.Displayname}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Only the PreDragEnter Event fires on Dragging over the cell. Both Columns are in the same Grid. 
The Effects shows the DragDropEffects.None sign.

Does someone has an idea what I did wrong? (Except choosing WPF for this project :-))

Comment: I would recommend [gong-wpf-dragdrop](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop) as it handles several cases for drag-and-drop, e.g this [issue](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop/issues/217)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your hint. I try to avoid external frameworks. My experience with them is, that you solve one problem and get two new ones.

Comment: My rule of thumb is to avoid reinventing the wheel :). Anyways, you could get some insight from the code...

Comment: To look into the code is a good idea. I will give it a try. Thanks again.

Comment: I did a workaround and replaced the TextBox to a TextBlock. No it's working.